# reloading a label from a viewcontroller2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, viewcontroller

Here  is my question in a simple format:

I have two views. 1 and 2.

2 has a label that populates with information from viewcontroller 1

Now, I would like to reload the label in view controller 2 by clicking a button on viewcontroller 2? [n.b. viewcontroller 2's label has randomized data that should change as you reload the label]

I tried so many methods and nothing seems to work.

Any idea?

Comment: So wats the issue ? cnt u use the same method ?

Comment: thanks for the question. which method do you mean? To give you more info: View controller 1 has multiple IBAction that would populate viewcontroller 2 depending on which button is pressed. On viewcontroller 2 I would like to add a button that would re-play the information without having to go back and click viewcontroller1's button.

Comment: So in Viewcontroller 2 simply on the button click change the value of the label like Label.Text = Variable which u mentioned

Comment: Make the information of vc1 public (properties @ .h file). Create a UIViewController property called parent @ vc2. @ vc1, do vc2.parent = self. Then you can access all vc1 properties from vc2, using parent.propertyname

Comment: I placed label.text = Variable in IBAction in 2 but it doesn't do anything. I have no idea what I'm missisng.

Comment: calin chitu. let me try the method you outlined. thanks. i'm, however, unsure what you mean but making it public.

Comment: a property declared @ .h file is public, @ .m is private.

Comment: Yup Calin Chitu. I am just missing the specifics of what exactly to do.

Comment: lecture 2 and 3 here will help you a lot. https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

Comment: where exactly do you do vc2.parent = self?

Comment: I did what you suggested but still getting the same results.